# PHP and SwfUpload

Tags: php, swfupload

I'm trying to implement [SwfUpload](http://swfupload.org/) in my web page, and I'm using php to save files on server. As is the first time I use this component, I choose to run the algoritm is suggested from the SwfUpload team (http://swfupload.org/forum/generaldiscussion/214): I've put it in a file and I've said the control to use it as code file.

It didn't work, as I'm asking help, but what really drives me crazy is that i really don't know how to debug that stuff! The request to the file is encapsulated into the flash object, and i can't get any feedback from it if something goes wrong.

Anyone is more experienced than me about this control?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do if all else fails is to make upload.php append to a log file your debug messages. Example: `file_put_contents("swfupload.log", print_r($_REQUEST, 1), FILE_APPEND);`

The only tricky thing about swfupload that you need to understand, is that the flash component is run with a different cookie jar (for security reasons), so you need to manually tell it (via a flash param) the session_id you currently have on the server, so when it makes the http request to `upload.php` it passes that session_id in a `$_GET` param and the php script starts the session with that specific id: `session_start($_GET['SESSION_ID']);`. From that point on,  `upload.php` behaves just like any other php code with your session data available. You get the `$_FILES`, move them to their respective folder, save them in db, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Well SWFUpload needs to upload the file to some script, so you can log to a file from within that script based on data received...

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's a pain to debug.

One way to get to the script output (which might be some fatal errors that you can't log or something) is to use a proxy like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) that shows you all http traffic.

It's sometimes hard to get flash using the proxy. You may need to configure the proxy in IE even if you use another browser.